# "Highest value offset for a given number of bars back" meaning?

Tags: pine-script, trading, tradingview-api, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I'm new to Pine script, please, anyone explain me exactly what this `high[abs(highestbars(amplitude))]` statement returns, specially in `highestbars(2)` definition what it mean Highest value offset?? FYI this statement is from Tradingview.com HalfTrend script,
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`highestbars()` will give you the bar index offset of the highest bar in the given range.

For example, if `highestbars(5)` returns `-2`, you know that the highest bar within the last 5 bars was 2 bars ago.